# What does the "struct AVCodec *codec" in "struct AVCodecContext" represent?

Tags: ffmpeg, media-player, decoder

I am using FFMpeg libraries in C/C++ to develop a media player .
[This source](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html) uses the following code to find the decoder of a video stream in a file :

`pCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);`  ,

where pCodecCtx is the pointer to the Codec Context of the video stream and pCodec is a pointer to AVCodec which was initialised to NULL .

If we have to explicitly find the decoder , then what is the `struct AVCodec *codec` found in `struct AVCodecContext` ? This is defined [here](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/libavcodec_2avcodec_8h_source.html#l01161) . Can someone please help me understand it's use .

Answer (score 0):

The AVCodec is a struct used to hold information about the codec such as codec name, etc.

See [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVCodec.html) for definition.

If you want to read the muxing.c example listed on the site, they use the AVCodec by itself to initialize the AVCodec within the AVCodecContext.

```
AVCodec *codec;
AVCodecID codec_id; // <-enum value (found based on the codec you enter)
AVCodecContext context;

//find and set encoder (or decoder) based on codec ID
codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codec_id);

//       or
// codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_id);

//Allocate encoding context for the AVCodec within AVCodecContext
context = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);

//Set the codec_id within AVCodecContext.
context->codec_id = codec_id;
```